# Cloudfront URL vs S3 URL on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I recently created a new cloudfront distribution of one of my s3 buckets. Should I change the URL to cloudfront.net domain? If I kept by S3 bucket URL, will the data be fetched from the nearest edge location for optimum delivery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to reference the new domain/bucketname that cloudfront gave you when you setup the distribution, otherwise your requests will bypass cloudfront and go directly to S3.

You can still use the S3 link, but that would defeat the purpose of having used cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

No, S3 does not fetched from the nearest edge location, this is done by Cloudfront. You can distribute your content directly from Amazon S3 or use Amazon S3 as an origin store for delivering content to your Amazon CloudFront edge locations.

> **Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)**, provides developers and IT teams with secure, durable, highly-scalable object storage. Amazon S3 is easy to use, with a simple web services interface to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere on the web.
>
> **Amazon CloudFront** can be used to deliver your entire website, including dynamic, static, streaming, and interactive content using a global network of edge locations. Requests for your content are automatically routed to the nearest edge location, so content is delivered with the best possible performance.